# Override autocmd to change filetype for a subset of markdown files

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I'd like to load the [cornelis plugin](https://github.com/isovector/cornelis) for the Agda language when I open a `*.lagda.md` file. I have this autocmd in `init.vim`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPre *.agda,*.lagda* setf agda
```

However, `*.lagda.md` gets `filetype=markdown` set instead, so the plugin for Agda doesn't load.

How can I get `*.lagda.md` to **not** be recognized as markdown?

Comment: Are you looking at a `*.agda.md` or a `*.lagda.md` file? Your autocommand would work on the latter, but not on the former, because you are missing the `*` at the end of the `*.agda` pattern.
Moreover, you should probably trigger on `BufNewFile` as well, since it will not work on new files otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, those were typos. I  do mean `.lagda.md` everywhere.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `BufReadPre` with `BufRead`?

Comment: No it does not work with `BufRead` either.

Comment: I just looked at the documentation of cornelis and it seems like `CornelisLoadWrapper` is not a function shipped with the plugin, but instead one you have to define yourself.
Have you done that? And if so, does it include `set filetype=agda` or `setfiletype agda`?

Moreover, the `ftdetect` file in the plugin should already handle the `*.lagda.*` case itself.
Do you have the directory of the plugin in your `runtimepath`?

Comment: The function is given in the README as an example configuration that I am following. The plugin works fine with `.agda` and `.lagda` files so it's not a problem with the plugin itself not being configured correctly, and really more about side-stepping the Markdown plugin.

Comment: This is a really frustrating behavior of `autocmd`, surely there is a standard solution for users to disambiguate when the same extension may be handled by two plugins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138018/discussion-between-ingo-and-li-yao-xia).

Comment: Do you consider the difference between `BufReadPre` and `BufRead` (aka `BufReadPost`) ?!

Comment: I don't know the difference and as stated earlier it does not seem to change things.

Comment: Thanks to Ingo that was resolved with `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.lagda.md set filetype=agda.markdown`. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it for free internet points.